# Matlab - Error bars for (large) noisy data sets

Tags: matlab, plot

[image: example nosiy data]

I have ten large linear arrays (n elements) such as

A = [ A1 A2....An ]
B = [ B1 B2....Bn ]
....
J = [ J1 J2....Jn ]

I can make an arithmentic mean of these arrays by adding them and dividing by ten and this reduces the noise substantially and shows the trend I am looking for. (note, that often I have more or less than ten data sets, but this is representative. Also, n varies, but is generally 10,000s of data points)

What I would like to do is plot this average with error bars that represent the noise in the original ten arrays. The arrays are large, so maybe error bars at sensible increments (say ten error bars across the entire range where the deviation from the average is greatest).

The image shows 10 noisy data sets plotted as grey lines with the mean as a black line.

thanks

Comment: I should make clear that the arrays contain data from a simulation that is inherently very noisy and sensitive to initial boundary conditions. I am running my simulation many times (i.e. 10x) to ascertain trends due to certain parameter changes. Hence taking the average, but I think it is honest to show the "error" bars which illustrate the noise in the data. For example, on an x,y axis, at any given x there will be 10 values for y. I plot the average y and want to show the min and max y which is the "error".

Comment: Why not just plot the 3 lines `min`, `mean` and `max` of the 10 arrays for each `n`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question with the plots as a bare minimum, show them as you have them now, and indicate (e.g. in paint) what should be changed. Preferably, add the code and data (mock-up data is OK, as long as it reproduces the problem), so we can have a look at it.

Comment: Could you describe how matlab's function `errorbar` does not work for what you want to do? seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Adriaan, I have added the plot. The data sets are enormous but essentially just a list of numbers. The code too is very simple, its just plot(A); hold on; ploy(B) etc. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have come to a rather laborious solution to this problem by writing a (what seems) lengthy piece of code.

The code takes all the input arrays and creates two new arrays. One which is the maximum y value for each x and one which is the miniumum. This is done with the max and min functions in matlab.

The minimum is substracted from the maximum to create an array of the magnitudes of the "error" at each value of x.

Then every nth value of the error array is plotted as an error bar on top of the arithmetic mean value of all the original input arrays.

It's a fix to the problem - and the screenshot shows the result - but I was wondering if there is a more elegant "built in" solution that does this in one shot.

[image]

Comment: So you made the error symmetric? What if it is not? Why not compute and overlay the standard deviation instead? Or the 95% confidence interval? You plot looks pretty, by the way!

Comment: BTW: if you show your code I can tell you if it can be done in less code. But there is no 1-liner that does this. You need to plot one line with `plot` for all your data, and one with `errorbar` for the subsampled data points with error bars.

Comment: the error is not symmetric.  It nearly is, but that is the nature of the data - the spread of data either side of the mean is almost the same. If you look (at for example the first two isotropic error points at 296K- also see the original plot in the original question, the spread is somwhat symmetric and increases with strain); I did consider plotting the centre markers of the error bars but the plot was becoming too cluttered. What I was trying to show was how the "spread" in measurements changes.